# Loop Through Objects on form except One Specific Text Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'd like to loop through all text boxes and cbo's in a form except for one specific text box (which contains the OpenArgs).  I'd like to ID all fields to make sure they are all filled in but this is an unbound form and sometimes will not have an OpenArgs in the form.

Even though .Value is not an drop down option in the VBA it does work, just doesn't consider it NULL using vbNullString.  I keep getting n = 0

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim n As Integer

n = 0

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.Name <> "txt_OpenARgs" Then
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
                    Case acTextBox, acComboBox ' adjust to taste
                        If ctl.Value = vbNullString  Then
                            n = n + 1
                            Debug.Print n
                        End If
        End Select
    End If
Next ctl

If n > 0 Then
    MsgBox "All fields must be populated before saving.", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
Else
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Try Nz instead vbNullString.

```
Dim ctl As Control
    Dim n As Integer

    n = 0

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name <> "txt_OpenARgs" Then
            Select Case ctl.ControlType
                        Case acTextBox, acComboBox ' adjust to taste
                            If Nz(ctl.Value,"") = "" Then
                                n = n + 1
                                Debug.Print n
                            End If
            End Select
        End If
    Next ctl

    If n > 0 Then
        MsgBox "All fields must be populated before saving.", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
    Else
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to use:

If ctl.Value & vbNullString = "" Then